# How to test throw new error JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, error-handling, throw

I'm trying to write unit-tests. In case the function gets the negative number it throws new error.

```
   Obj = function () { 
}; 
Obj.prototype.Count = function (number) { 
    if (number < 0) { 
        throw new Error("There is no function for negative numbers"); 
    } else...
```

My unit-tet function:

```
function test(then,expected) {
        results.total++;
        var m1=new Obj();
        if (m1.Count(then)!=expected){
          results.bad++;
            alert(m1.Count(then)+" not equal "+expected);
        }
    }
    var results = {
        total: 0,
        bad: 0
    };
```

Then I'm trying to run the tests

```
test(5,120) 
test(-5, "There is no function for negative numbers");
```

The first one works correctly, but I don't know what to write to 'expected' for negative numbers. The example doesn't work.
Could you advise me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: It is kind of test usually called Expected Exception. You want to write your own JS test framework? Or you want to test your code? Because if second - there are lots ready made test frameworks for JS out there.

Comment: I just want to test my code.

Comment: Then I would suggest to pick existing framework, for example this one, it has check for exception http://api.qunitjs.com/throws/

Comment: You would have to catch the exception and the expected result for a negative number would be a particular exception.

Comment: @ jfriend00 should I use try and catch? So I have to make different test functions for negative and positive numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to test errors, you'll need to use a *try ... catch*.

```
var Obj = function() {};
Obj.prototype.count = function(num) {
    if (num < 0) throw new Error("Invalid Number");
    else return 0;
}

function test(value, expected) {
    results.total++;
    var obj = new Obj();
    try {
        obj.count(value);
    }
    catch (err) {
        if (err.message != expected) results.bad++;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
test(-5, 'Invalid Number'); // doesn't add one to results.bad
```